# How to import exporting.js and export-data.js using angular2-highcharts and AOT compiler?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular2-aot, angular2-highcharts

I'm using angular2-highcharts and my chart works just fine, but I need to export the chart to XLS.

All I need to achieve this is doing

```
HighchartsExporting(Highcharts);
HighchartsExportData(Highcharts);
```

somewhere in the code, and the export options will show up by the chart.

The problem is how to import HighchartsExporting and HighchartsExportData properly, because the [standard solution](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#add-highcharts-modules)

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      BrowserModule, 
      ChartModule.forRoot(
        require('highcharts'),
        require('highcharts/modules/exporting')
      ],
```

won't work with AOT, giving me some *"Error encountered resolving symbol values statically"* at compile time.

I can get it to work by doing

```
import * as HichartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import * as HighchartsExportData from 'highcharts/modules/export-data';
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/issues/126), but it gives me 2 errors:

- *Error   TS2497: Module '"xxxx/highcharts/modules/exporting"' resolves
  to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.* - JIT compilation
- *Cannot find module 'highcharts/modules/export-data'.* - AOT compilation

I can get around this by doing

```
import HichartsExporting  = require('highcharts/modules/exporting');
import HighchartsExportData = require('highcharts/modules/export-data');
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415661/what-does-resolves-to-a-non-module-entity-and-cannot-be-imported-using-this), but after AOT compilation, I get "*Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined*" at runtime.

All solutions seem to work fine in practice, I just can't compile them. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case this helps anyone, I couldn't do it using imports. Instead, I had to include the `<script src="~/node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js">` tag in my HTML. Since this JS is a self-invoking function, that's all it takes to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of `Highcharts` with all modules loaded like `HighchartsModule(Highcharts)` and then pass the instance to `forRoot` function as explained in the [angular2-highcharts docs](https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#access-to-the-highcharts-static-api).

You should be able to load the modules using `require` or `import`.

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
```

or

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
HC_exporting(Highcharts);
```

and next the same as in the mentioned docs:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
      BrowserModule, 
      ChartModule.forRoot(
-       require('highcharts'),
+       Highcharts
      )
    ],
})
```

Comment: The only problem is "import * as HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';" gives me that "resolves to a non-module entity" error.